# UJS-like AJAX response in Rails 3

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

Rails 3 uses UJS approach, which allows to handle AJAX responses from JavaScript code.

```
$("form").live("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr){
    $(".target").html(data.myHTML);
});
```

How view in Rails 3 should look like to fill "data" object, so i can inspect is from JavaScript ?

Regular rendering, using "js.erb", or "js.haml" results "data" local variable in JavaScript "undefined".

Of course, in the view, i can use some global variable, like following ("js.haml"):

```
- c = escape_javascript(render "search_result")
:plain
  var ajaxResponse = "#{c}";
```

… And call it from JavaScript handler, like this:

```
$("form").live("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr){
    $(".target").html(ajaxResponse);
});
```

… but it breaks incapsulation.

Ideal way would be using "data" local variable.

So, how the view should look like ?